# Как загрузить картинку в ListView.

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: Пропарсить json файл и вывести информацию в ListView, в файле есть текст и есть ссылки на изображения. Как загрузить изображения, по ссылке, с файла, в ListView? Пару статей нашел по этому поводу, но не смог сними разобраться. 
Вот код:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
             JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.0.152/1/large2.json");

                try{

                JSONArray  commands = json.getJSONArray("Animals");

                    for(int i=0;i < commands.length();i++){

                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        JSONObject e = commands.getJSONObject(i);

                        map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                                    map.put("name", "Title:" + e.getString("name"));

                                    map.put("action_command", "Action: " +  e.getString("action"));
                                    url = new URL("http://"+e.getString("image"));

                                    Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

                                    imageview.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);

                                    mylist.add(map);

                }

                }catch(JSONException e)        {

                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list,
                    new String[] {"name", "action_command"},
                    new int[] { R.id.author, R.id.text});

               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не смогли разобраться? На всякий случай приведу ссылку где подробно описано http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android/78747/. Вам нужно расширить реализовать свой ListAdapter и в методе getView(...) загружать нужный Bitmap в ImageView соответствуюшей ячейки.

Сорри что так скомкано просто по этому поводу уже написаны тонны статей и не разобраться просто невозможно

Comment: Вот эту статью, на хабре, я не видел. Спасибо, она помогла.

Answer (score 1):

http://dajver.blogspot.com/2011/12/listview-android.html вот тут описано как сделаеть картинки в списке

Comment: Нето, мне надо было загружать с интернета и постепенно. Но всё равно спасибо.