# Изображение в listview

Tags: java, android

Получаю изображение по ссылке, как отправить его в лист вью? С текстом мне понятно а вот изображение...

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView))
            .execute("http://сайт/90a6ba1d5c44fb5a504f572d6fa34619.jpg");
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();

}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.layout, чето там);
    }
}
```

В макете лист вью всего 1 images

Comment: Мне кажется в данном вопросе недостаточно информации, для точного ответа. Возможно вы забыли сделать notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: ну вот я передавал текст final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ChatActivity.this, UploadsList,
                                R.layout.chat, new String[]{"name", "text"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.mess}); тут понятно. А как через адаптер отправить изображение

Comment: @Xyz, если вы хотите нормально сделать, то вам нужно создать свой, кастомный адаптер, чтобы получить полный контроль над разметкой элемента списка. Также грузить самостоятельно картинки из ети - моветон, в виду наличия множества библиотек для этого. Например `Glide` - загружает и кэширует картинку в одну строку. Никаких `AsyncTask`-ов не надо будет делать.

Comment: Кастомный адаптер я создал, он работает но как "отправить " в него изображение. new SimpleAdapter(зис,что отправляю, разметка а дальше как?

Comment: @Xyz Это не кастомный адаптер. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как загрузить картинку в ListView.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/76267/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-listview)